# I am trying to get more spacing in my combo box in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to get more spacing in the combo box menu:

[image]

The first column is room and the second column is building. As you can see, the first few entries don't show nicely. I would like to have more padding in each column. Is there a simply trick? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `ColumnWidths` property of the combo box. It's on the Format tab under `Column count`.

The default width per column is 2.54 cm (1 inch), you might try e.g. `3.5cm;1.5cm`